# Direct upload to Rackspace's Cloud Files

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, uploadify, rackspace, cloudfiles

I'm working on a solution for video upload.  I have a Rails 3.1 app, and the basic needs are for the files to be uploaded to Rackspace's Cloud Files, then we'll do some encoding, and then we can display the video files to the users.  My problem seems to be in my decision to use Cloud Files, because I can find solutions everywhere for direct upload to S3, but nothing on how to do the same for Cloud Files.  I run the app on Heroku which doesn't have a large capacity on it's file system, so uploading it to the server then uploading it to Cloud Files is out of the question.  If anyone has a solution to this, or an idea, I would love to hear it, because I have been stumped for the better part of a day now.

Also for reference, this is a blog post I've been using to get to the point that I'm at: http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/video-encoding-with-uploadify-carrierwave-and-zencoder

The author of the article is having the files uploaded to the server, and then to Cloud Files but apparently he's running this somewhere where he has a bigger server.  My app crashed on Heroku when I tried his solution with a 150mb file, and I'm expecting the videos to be the size or larger, so I have to find another way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Rackspace Cloud files have an API that can be used for uploading to. 
http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide-20110913.pdf

I'm sure you've already seen this... but it might be able to be modified to upload to Rackspace instead of S3.

https://github.com/contrast/uploadify-s3

Answer (score 1):

Rackspace doesn't support preflight requests, so you'd have to use flash...
I'm currently working with S3 and this library - http://cotag.github.com/Condominios/ trying to get my head around AngularJS!